# What is wrong with the JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a little time killer project for myself, as a way to wait for a forum post.

```
var factsArray = ['MIT has created a 3D version of Scratch, called StarLogo', 'Duck echos DO quack', 'Ostriches never stick their head in the sand', 'The cigarrete lighter was invented before the match']
var i = 0;
function start() {
     while (i < 20) {
          setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = factsArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * factsArray.length)];}, 3000);
          i = i + 1;
     }
     setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = "Sixty seconds are up! Go and post!";}, 3000);
}
```

That's my code; so far, it will only show one item from the array and stop there.

What I want it to do is display one fact from my factsArray every 3 seconds, until 60 seconds has passed, then it will display "Sixty seconds are up! Go and post!".

Why is my code only showing one fact, not one every 3 seconds?

Comment: I think you want to do `3000 * i`

Comment: `setTimeout` doesn't pause the script. Please improve your title and description.

Comment: Are you sure it's only showing one item from the array? Or are your timeouts all being executed at once, and you see the final result?

Comment: @tymeJV: What's the difference? If OP only sees the final result, then that's the same as it showing only one item from the array. :-P

Comment: Not sure why this was put on hold, seems like he wants to put out a fact every 3 seconds, for 60 seconds.  Doesn't seem like he made any edits, and it looks pretty clear to me.

Comment: @CrazyTrain -- Was hoping it sparked some innovation :). As he says, it only shows one item and stops there :D

Comment: @Jordan -- Probably because the code itself works fine and there is no question.

Comment: I agree with @tymeJV. It's always nice when a question actually describes a problem.

Comment: @Jordan if it's clear to you, then please edit it so that it makes sense to a larger crowd.

Comment: @tymeJV I guess, but it is rather clear what he wants to do, and his code doesn't do what he wants.  Then again, mic already answered what the problem almost definitely is, so I guess it works out :P

Comment: @ChrisFarmer Good point, I forgot I can do that now :P

Comment: Second @mic 's comment/answer, plus you want your final timeout = 60000

Comment: @mic Good point. Final timeout should be 63000.

Comment: I mean the timeout for "Sixty seconds are up"

Comment: I see. Right you are.

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` is quasi-asynchronous, this code adds 20 timeouts at nearly the same time so they also end at the same time. You will want to set only one timeout and start the next one in the timeout's callback if the total timeout has not been reached yet. Similarily the last statement should be added if the total timeout has been reached.

You could also work with `setInterval` and `clearInterval` to implement this.